# Pandas - Set DateTimeIndex on Melted DF

Tags: python, pandas

```
    price   size
0   6759.0  19493
1   6758.5  39015
2   6758.0  31137
3   6757.5  30
4   6757.0  2730
5   6756.5  1290
6   6756.0  4287
7   6755.5  20117
8   6755.0  227173
9   6754.5  368844
10  6754.0  618665
11  6753.5  9000
12  6753.0  28846
13  6752.5  72021
14  6752.0  229463
15  6751.5  110
16  6751.0  13008
17  6750.5  15150
18  6750.0  65950
19  6749.5  19916
```

Melt,set column names and take values only:

```
df = df.melt().T
df.columns = [colnames]
df = df[-1:]
```

To produce the final df I want to set the index of:

```
    sell_price_10   sell_price_9    sell_price_8    sell_price_7    sell_price_6    sell_price_5    sell_price_4    sell_price_3    sell_price_2    sell_price_1    buy_price_1 buy_price_2 buy_price_3 buy_price_4 buy_price_5 buy_price_6 buy_price_7 buy_price_8 buy_price_9 buy_price_10    sell_size_10    sell_size_9 sell_size_8 sell_size_7 sell_size_6 sell_size_5 sell_size_4 sell_size_3 sell_size_2 sell_size_1 buy_size_1  buy_size_2  buy_size_3  buy_size_4  buy_size_5  buy_size_6  buy_size_7  buy_size_8  buy_size_9  buy_size_10
value   6759    6758.5  6758    6757.5  6757    6756.5  6756    6755.5  6755    6754.5  6754    6753.5  6753    6752.5  6752    6751.5  6751    6750.5  6750    6749.5  19493   39015   31137   30  2730    1290    4287    20117   227173  368844  618665  9000    28846   72021   229463  110 13008   15150   65950   19916
```

This has worked for me in the past, but gives a `ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only` error when setting the new index when I try with this df.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(round(time.time(),0), unit='s')
df.set_index(df['time'], inplace=True)
df.drop(['time'],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: are you trying to replace `value` (the row index) with the current time?

Comment: yep, correct   (char limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to set the index by simply passing an iterable the same length as the length of the data frame.

starting with your initial dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': [6759.0, 6758.5, 6758.0, 6757.5, 6757.0, 6756.5, 
              6756.0, 6755.5, 6755.0, 6754.5, 6754.0, 6753.5, 
              6753.0, 6752.5, 6752.0, 6751.5, 6751.0, 6750.5, 
              6750.0, 6749.5],
    'size': [19493, 39015, 31137, 30, 2730, 1290, 4287, 20117, 
             227173, 368844, 618665, 9000, 28846, 72021, 229463, 
             110, 13008, 15150, 65950, 19916]
})
```

First set the index to the columns names that you want eventually

```
a, b = zip(*[('sell_price_%d' % i, 'buy_price_%d' % i) for i in range(1,11)])

df.index = a+b # a+b would be your colnames
```

Then construct a new DataFrame from the current df transposed

```
df2 = df.T[:1]
```

and set its index

```
df2.index = [pd.to_datetime(round(time.time(),0), unit='s')]

df2
# outputs:
                     sell_price_1  sell_price_2  sell_price_3  sell_price_4  \
2018-04-10 01:27:59        6759.0        6758.5        6758.0        6757.5

                     sell_price_5  sell_price_6  sell_price_7  sell_price_8  \
2018-04-10 01:27:59        6757.0        6756.5        6756.0        6755.5

                     sell_price_9  sell_price_10  buy_price_1  buy_price_2  \
2018-04-10 01:27:59        6755.0         6754.5       6754.0       6753.5

                     buy_price_3  buy_price_4  buy_price_5  buy_price_6  \
2018-04-10 01:27:59       6753.0       6752.5       6752.0       6751.5

                     buy_price_7  buy_price_8  buy_price_9  buy_price_10
2018-04-10 01:27:59       6751.0       6750.5       6750.0        6749.5
```